# Multiple ErrorHandler in Scala Play 2.4.x

Tags: scala, error-handling, playframework

In the docs it's pretty easy to specify a custom error handler, e.g. play.http.errorHandler in the conf file. However, is it possible to have multiple error handlers specific to controllers - in my case I have an API that I want to return a JSON message as an error, and then some routes that would return an HTML error page.

Comment: Maybe instead of having multiple error handlers you could just check the content-type of the request inside the single error handler? If it is application/json then you could return the JSON error response otherwise use the HTML view?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's possible a content-type isn't provided though but I ended up doing something similar (though kind of hacky) in that I just check that the path has /api/ in it as all my api routes are formatted that way. Thanks!